# Why when starting the backgroundworker its never get into the timer tick event while downloading the files?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button click event where i start the backgroundworker:

```
private void beginOperationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Then in i have the backgroundworker do work event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            timer2.Enabled = true;
            ei = new ExtractImages(StartTags, LastTags, Maps, localFilename, UrlsPath);
        }
```

I used a breakpoint it does do the timer2.Enabled = true; line.
But then its doing the second line that download many files and i see that it does download the files.

But i have also this timer2 tick event:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            label4.Text = counter.ToString();
        }
```

But its never get to the timer2 tick event since its downloading the file from the other class.

I wanted to run a timer and see how many seconds it takes to download all the files.

How do i make that it will download the files and also count the seconds in the timer2 tick event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to keep in mind.

1. You have to set the interval of `timer`.
2. You can also do `timer2.Start();`